# Selenium not scroll down

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an issue in selenium.
I want to scroll down the page and I created this method:

```
public static void scrollDownToEndOfPage()
    {
        By locator;
        locator = By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Blocked advertisers')]//ancestor::nz-form-item//nz-select//input");
        WebDriver driver2 = WebDriverMgr.getDriver();
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver2;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver2).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", locator);
    }
```

When I debug nothing happened, this is the logs

```
Wed Dec 18 18:35:14 IST 2019:INFO: WebDriver: Script - window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
Wed Dec 18 18:35:14 IST 2019:INFO: WebDriver: Script - window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
Wed Dec 18 18:35:14 IST 2019:INFO: WebDriver: Script - window.scrollBy(0,250)
Wed Dec 18 18:35:14 IST 2019:ERROR: Argument is of an illegal type: org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath
Wed Dec 18 18:35:14 IST 2019:INFO: WebDriver: Script - arguments[0].scrollIntoView();


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is of an illegal type: org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.WebElementToJsonConverter.apply(WebElementToJsonConverter.java:83)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
```

and this is the screen after I run the scroll 
[image]

the page is a draw that opened from the side of the screen, And I want to scroll it down can someone advise?

The solution worked as Sooraj suggestion

```
 public static void scrollToElement(By locator)
    {

      //  locator = By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Blocked advertisers')]//ancestor::nz-form-item//nz-select//input");
        WebDriver driver2 = WebDriverMgr.getDriver();
        WebElement element = driver2.findElement(locator);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver2;
       // js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
      //  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver2).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
      //  js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You have to pass in the found WebElement, not a locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with javascript scrollIntoView and pass an element which you want to interact with in the non viewable area:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

Comment: I did what you told I put in locator the xpath of the field I am not see and get    Wed Dec 18 18:19:39 IST 2019:ERROR: Argument is of an illegal type: org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath
Wed Dec 18 18:19:39 IST 2019:INFO: WebDriver: Script - arguments[0].scrollIntoView();

Comment: I tried this     By locator;
        locator = By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Blocked')]//ancestor::nz-form-item//nz-select//input");

Comment: js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", locator);

Comment: @Bastian, The exception says It is the problem with the Xpath. Please add the html as code in the question

Comment: but get this error. I just want the side form that is opened to scroll down.  I managed to fill the form, however I have some fields in the buttom of the form and can not reach them

Comment: @Bastian, you cannot send a **By** as an argument to the method, it accepts only web element.

Comment: Please be more specific, I want to see this field, what shall I send/ can you give any example.

Comment: I uploaded a new pic still not work as you can see the Xpath is a valid, but not seen.   I need it to scroll down, it is a side form that opened I just want it to scrolled down. If I put break point in the middle of the form and manually scroll it is working, just need it to be scrolled